# Automator Javascript - see console.log output

Tags: automator

I'm trying to get all object properties and I use

```
console.log(object)
```

But I don't understand where to find output? Is there a special Automator function for logging?

[image]

---

UPD

Using script editor. Calling console.log(object) just output type of object. Is there a way to see list of all properties/values like in web inspector?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you use the Script Editor application to debug your JavaScript first? This application has a console that works.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I tried to use Script Editor, but I don't understand how to see all object's properties. console.log just returns type of the object

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution that will work in most cases is to just use `JSON.stringify(obj)` to see the object as a string in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Console log messages appear in apple script editor in the lower display area under the messages tab. If it's hidden, show with menu option View, Show Log, Messages..

log an object with

```
var obj = {x:1, y:0};  
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```